# Pycharm pytest run configuration - how to remove redundant argument

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

Every time I'm trying to run Pytest with debugger - unexpected "-k" argument is passing automatically and this causes run error. I can't find this argument anywhere in Run/Debug configuration settings, I've even tried to remove all configurations from settings but this '-k' is still there. How my run configuration looks like:

[image: Run/configuration screenshot]

Error text:

> ERROR: Wrong expression passed to `**'-k'**`: --namespace autotests --drop_fixtures --disable-warnings -s: at column 13: expected end of input; got identifier

While running:

`--target test_montly_billing.py::test_monthly_billing_registration_success -- **-k** *(Why is it here?)* "--namespace autotests --drop_fixtures --disable-warnings -s" Testing started at 10:25 AM ...`

How can I find from where this argument gets from?

Answer (score 1):

Move `--namespace autotests ...` from the "Keywords" field to "Additional Arguments". `-k` stands for "keywords" which you are passing to pytest (by mistake I guess).